# Confused about directional derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors

I have the following question:

> Calculate the directional derivative of the function at the point and in direction indicated.
>
> $f(x, y) = \arctan(xy)$ at $(1, 2)$ along the line $y = 2x$ in the direction of increasing $x$.

When I looked at the solution, I was confused about the way they solved it:
[image]

I understand that we need a gradient vector at (1,2) and some unit vector to give the direction.

I also understand that since it is in the direction of increasing x, x will be positive.
However, how did they get that it is going to be along the line (1,2).
Did they set x = t and then got parametric equations where x = t, and y = 2t?
If so, are the coefficient before t our vector that gives us the direction?

Also, I'm so confused about the use of parametric equations with directional derivatives. Could someone explain relationship between parametric equations and directional derivatives?

Comment: $$\pmatrix{x \\ y} = \pmatrix{t \\ 2t} = t\pmatrix{1 \\ 2}$$  So the direction of the line $y=2x$ is $\langle 1,2\rangle$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going along the line $y = 2x$ then you find it's directional vector by looking at $\vec{OP}$ where $O = (0,0)$ and $P$ is a point on the line. Take $P = (1,2)$ then the directional vector is $\vec{OP} = \langle1,2 \rangle$.

Comment: But could we try another point? Not (1,2), but something else? Would the answer be different?

Comment: @Jack Try a different point on the line.  What happens if you choose, say, the point $(-3,-6)$ (verify that this is on the line $y=2x$)?

Comment: @Bye_World Since in (-3, -6), x = -3 (it's negative). But we need the direction in increasing x. So, if I try something like (3,6), it would have the same results as (1,2) vector, right?

Comment: @Jack Ah.  You're right.  It asks for $D_vf$ for along $y=2x$ for increasing $x$.  Then yes try $(3,6)$ instead.  You will get the same answer (but try it yourself anyway to see why).

Comment: @Bye_World Thank you! That makes so much sense right now. So, just to clarify, we can either construct parametric equations and then pick the coefficient before "t" to be our direction vector, or we can choose any point that lies on our line?

Comment: @Jack You should use the parametrized equations or *two* points on the line.  It just so happens that one of the points on this line was the origin so for any point $P(x,y)$ on the line, $\vec{OP}=\langle x,y\rangle$ will be parallel to the line.  In general you want $P(x_1,y_1)$ and $Q(x_2,y_2)$ and then the direction parallel to your line will be $\vec{PQ} = \langle x_2-x_1,y_2-y_1\rangle$.

Comment: @Bye_World Thank your for the answers! But sometimes they give you set of parametric equations but not any points. And when they do, I'm having a hard time getting the direction vector for our directional derivative.

Comment: @Jack Well it's hard to give definitive strategies for every type of problem.  But when you get stuck on one, you can always ask here.

Comment: @Bye_World THank you so much, you clarified confusion I had about directional derivatives and parametric equations! Now, should I accept the answer above or you would post your comments as a separate answer and then I would accept it ?